# How to disable vibration and sound on touch in Android programmatically?

Tags: android

I am making one application and opening alertdialog using OnLongClickListener of ImageView and also ontouch zooming. But when I pressed long than vibrating on so is it possible to turn off vibrating on long click listener. I am using below code:

```
public OnLongClickListener longClick = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)DailySatsangActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
        vibe.cancel();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is **Haptic Feedback** instead of the normal vibration.

You can turn-off "Haptic Feedback" by using below code,

**XML attribute:** `android:hapticFeedbackEnabled //set it true or false in view's xml file for the desired result.`

**Java method:** `setHapticFeedbackEnabled(boolean)`

**OR**

You can use **Audio Manger** class to disable sound and vibration, have a look at [setRingerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29) method of Audio Manager class.

**Example :**

```
AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setRingerMode(aManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class for this.